# How to store custom registration fields in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am adding few new fields to my registration form. All the default field are stored in database except custom field.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'company_name' => 'required',
    ]);
}

 protected function create(array $data)
{
        $user = User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
          'company_name' => $data['company_name'],
          'role' => 'client',
       ]);


        return $user;
}
```

Here is my form

```
<form action="/register" method = "post" id = "reg_form">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="company_name" id="email" placeholder="Name of your Company"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="re_pass" placeholder="Re enter password"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" class="btn" id="register_sbt_btn" value="Register"/>
  </div>

  </div>
  </form>
```

The `company_name` and `role` doesn't get stored. I am giving a default value to the `role => client` whenever a new user registers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to add the fields on `$fillable` attribute of `User` model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'company_name', //<--- HERE
    'role', //<--- HERE
];
```

Also make sure that you have those fields on `Users` table